# A representation of the symmetric group on tensor space.

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

While answering [this question on common eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049755/how-to-determine-the-existence-of-certain-common-eigenvectors-in-a-simpler-way)  I wondered about the natural generalisation. Although I can deal with small cases I cannot find the general answer.

Let  $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $W$ be the $k$-fold tensor power $W=V\otimes \dots\otimes V$.

We have an obvious representation $\Psi$ of the symmetric group $S_k$ on $W$ given by
$$
\Psi(\pi):v_1\otimes v_2\otimes\dots\otimes v_k \mapsto v_{1\pi}\otimes v_{2\pi}\otimes\dots\otimes v_{k\pi}
$$
where linear maps and permutations are being written on the right.

The original question was the case $k=3$ and asked about simultaneous eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $S_3$.

**In the more general case  a natural question is  (i) what is the multiplicity of the trivial representation in  $\Psi$; (ii) what is the multiplicity of the sign representation in $\Psi$.**

I believe that the answers can be expressed in terms of binomial coefficients; if so, is there an "easy"  combinatorial explanation? (I say "easy", because the representation theory of the symmetric group is all combinatorics anyway - I am wondering if there's an immediate way to see what the answers to the questions are.)

Comment: It might help to Google "Schur-Weyl duality"

Comment: @Nate Indeed, I remember (though now vaguely!) this stuff: the very first graduate lectures I attended (c. 1963) were devoted to the topic (as a prelude to characteristic $p$ case). I suppose I am hoping for something that doesn't need the full machinery of the rep theory of the symmetric and general linear groups.

Answer (score 1):

Well as I suggested in the comments, Schur-Weyl duality gives a complete answer for how to decompose $V^{\otimes k}$ as an $S_k$ representation.

If you just want to understand the space of invariants, there is a purely combinatorial argument.

Let $N$ be an $n$ element set, and let's think of $V$ as $\mathbb{C} \langle N \rangle$ (the vector space of formal linear combinations of elements of $N$).  The tensor power $V^{\otimes k}$ is then isomorphic to $\mathbb{C} \langle N^k \rangle$, with the action of $S_k$ coming from the action on $N^k$ by permuting the coordinates.

Here is a general lemma about combinatorial representation theory:  If $G$ is a finite group acting on a finite set $X$, then the space of $G$-invariant vectors in $\mathbb{C}\langle X \rangle$ has a basis given by elements $\sum_{x\in O} x$ where $O$ is a G-orbit in $X$.  In particular the dimension of the space of invariants is equal to the number of orbits.

Applying this to our setting where $G = S_k$ and $X = N^k$, we want to count the $S_k$ orbits on $N^k$.   Two $k$-tuples in $N^k$ are in the same orbit iff for each $n \in N$ that $n$ appears the same number of times in the two $k$-tuples. Keeping track of the multiplicity of each $n \in N$, we can recognize this as a stars-and-bars type counting problem, which gives $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1} = \binom{n+k-1}{k}$ orbits -- and hence a that dimensional space of invariants.

Comment: Thank you ... I think that the number of occurrences of the sign representation plus this is twice the dimension of the space of $A_k$ invariants, but I can't quite see what that is either.

Comment: @Nate Can you explain how from Schur-Weyl duality we can get the decomposition as an $S_k$-module of $V^{\otimes k}$? In other words, how do we get the decomposition into $S_k$-irreducibles from the decomposition into $GL_n\times S_k$-irreducibles?

Comment: @JoseBrox To go from a $GL_n \times S_k$ decomposition to just an $S_k$ one just replace the $GL_n$ representations by their dimensions. For the decomposition $V^{k} = \bigoplus_\lambda W(\lambda) \otimes S^\lambda$, this means $S^\lambda$ is occurring $dim(W(\lambda))$ many times.